# NodeJS loading a website and removing an element from the page before rendering

Tags: node.js, screenshot, phantomjs, casperjs

I have recently messed around with NodeJs and it loading any website and saving a screenshot.  To be more specific, I have used PhantomJS to load the website and save a screenshot.  I have also used CasperJS and ZombieJS, but none of these tools really allow you to mess around with the resources of the website before loading.  Is it even possible?

To be clear, I would like to load any website, lets say stackoverflow.com and calculate load time and save a screenshot.  That's easy, but on second run I want to load the same website and remove jquery resource for example and then calculate load time of that.

It looks like phantomjs and casperjs have callbacks like onResourceRequested or onResourceReceived but there is not method to abort a request.  Is it possible?  I would not want to proxy the request via some php script that does this but that is the alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like this is not possible but it is a feature on the phantomjs roadmap: http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=230